# Override Prestashop Core controller using a module

Tags: prestashop

Working on a project that consist to create thumbs for the product's features,
is there a way to **override**  the core controller  `*AdminFeaturesController*`using a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your module you can create a `/override` directory. Under this directory you will create this file `/override/controllers/admin/AdminFeaturesController.php`.

This file should look as follow:

```
<?php

class AdminFeaturesController extends AdminFeaturesControllerCore 
{
    // Only override the functions that should be modified
    public function function_that_i_want_to_override() {

    }

}
```

The override will be effective after module installation.